# Import local js function to node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm stuck on this for a while now and think this is because I misunderstand the linking of files in node.js.

I have the following structure:

```
./main_test.html
./js_test.js
./node_test.js
```

The `main_test.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p1">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The js_test includes a function to print text to the `<p>` tag with id `p1` and is this:

```
module.exports.print_to_p = function(){
$("#p1").text('This worked.');
};
```

My node script should serve the `main_test.html` and run the function from `js_test.js`:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
$ = require('jQuery'),
port = 1337,
dep1 = require('./js_test.js');

dep1.print_to_p();

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
fs.readFile("main_test.html", function(error, data) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
});
}).listen(port);
```

It says `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` which I assumed was due to it not referencing JQuery but changing this to `document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'This worked';` didn't solve this.

How can I run the Javascript/JQuery in my node app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your http-request cannot handle your linked files as they are all interpreted as html-files. 
If you let your server handle different file types using the same content-type the dependencies are not delivered correctly. You could either fix this using some libraries or packages like [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) or [mime-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) (which helps to individually identify content-types), or you could do it manually by identifying the content-types of your dependent files and adjusting your request.

An example to do this would be to modify your `node_test.js` as follows:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
port = 1337,
path = require('path');

var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var filePath = request.url;
    var extension = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';  // your default content-type

    switch (extension) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;

        ...  // here you can specify the content-types you need 
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, data) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': contentType
        });
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(port);
```

Note that you also have to specify the file to be read here! The http-request is called for every dependent file independently which means that each file has to be handled and read. 
In order to get the correct file extensions you can use a node-package called [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path).

Answer (score 0):

Node is a server language and has no access to DOM. You may create Node server, which will host HTML and JS files, but you won't be able to run client-side JS code in Node.

Your code should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js_test.js"></script>
<script> print_to_p(); </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p1">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

js_test.js

```
function print_to_p(){
$("#p1").text('This worked.');
};
```

node_test.js

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
port = 1337,

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
fs.readFile("main_test.html", function(error, data) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
});
}).listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what this line in `node_test.js` would need for it to work.

```
dep1.print_to_p();
```

The function's code is referencing jQuery `$` variable but since `js_test.js` doesn't define one it leads to error.

Another thing, even if `$` would be defined it'll halt to not being aware of the html-page itself. This is Node.js that is being run on the server. It would work better if you used "server-friendly jQuery" implementation, cheerio for example. Or if you would move that piece of JavaScript code to be run on your HTML page.

You're close, keep working on it. The missing link is to realize what is being run on the server and what is being run on the browser.